# One column in a table referring to another column where there are duplicate data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to build simple database system about bike (or bicycle) rental store.

**Here are the tables, and columns in parantheses:**

```
Model (MNr, Modelname, dayprice)

Bike (MNr, CopyNr, Frame, Color)

Customer (CNr, Name, Surename, MobileNr)

Rental (CNr, MNr, CopyNr, DateOut, DateIn)
```

(MNr stands for model number, CNr stands for customer number).

Models are bike models, Bike table shows data on each particular bike.

There can be several bikes of each model, to distinguish between them 
"CopyNr" column is used, where each bike in a given model is numbered 1, 2, 3, etc.

Rental: A rental relationship always applies to only one bike and one customer.

So I put the following primary and foreign keys:

```
Model (MNr (PK), Modelname, dayprice)
Bike (MNr (FK), CopyNr (PK), Frame, Color)
Customer (CNr (PK), Firstame, Surname, MobileNr)
Rent (CNr (FK), MNr (FK), CopyNr (FK), DateOut, DateIn)
```

The "CopyNr" at "Rental" is referring to the "CopyNr" of "Bikes". So I used "CopyNr" as 
primary key column.

**But that column can contain duplicate values, like there can be copy nr 2 of model A and copy nr 2 of 
model B.
And primary key columns don't allow duplicate values.**

I wrote the following in the SQL file, and when but it on PHPMyAdmin.

Here's the code from SQL code:

[It had Norwegian names, I changed it to English, thus color names are Norwegian]

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.8.4
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1:3306
-- Generation Time: Feb 04, 2020 at 07:15 PM
-- Server version: 10.2.26-MariaDB-log
-- PHP Version: 7.1.30

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+01:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- 
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `Customer`
--

CREATE TABLE `Customer` (
  `CNr` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `Firstname` varchar(20),
  `Surname` varchar(20),
  `MobileNr` varchar(8),
  PRIMARY KEY (CNr)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `Customer` (`CNr`, `Firstname`, `Surname`, `MobileNr`) VALUES
(1, 'Olav', 'Petterses', '88888888'),
(2, 'Petter', 'Olavsson', '44444444');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `Model`
--

CREATE TABLE `Model` (
  `MNr` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `Modelname` varchar(20),
  `Dayprice` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (MNr)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `Model` (`MNr`, `Modelname`, `Dayprice`) VALUES
(2, 'FirstPrice', 10),
(15, 'DBS', 50),
(16, 'DBS', 60);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `Bike`
--

CREATE TABLE `Bike` (
  `MNr` int(5),
  `CopyNr` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `Frame` int(3),
  `Color` varchar(10),
   PRIMARY KEY (`CopyNr`, `MNr`),
   CONSTRAINT `Bike_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`MNr`) REFERENCES `Model` (`MNr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Bike` (`MNr`, `CopyNr`, `Frame`, `Color`) VALUES
(2, 1, 55, 'rød'),
(15, 1, 65, 'rød'),
(16, 1, 55, 'grønn'),
(2, 2, 55, 'rød'),
(15, 2, 65, 'grønn');


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `Rent`
--

CREATE TABLE `Rent` (
  `CNr` int(2),
  `MNr` int(5),
  `CopyNr` int(2),
  `DatoUt` date,
  `DateInn` date,
  CHECK (`DatoUt` < `DateInn`),
  CONSTRAINT `Rent_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`MNr`) REFERENCES `Model` (`MNr`),
  CONSTRAINT `Rent_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`CopyNr`) REFERENCES `Bike` (`CopyNr`),
  CONSTRAINT `Rent_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`CNr`) REFERENCES `Customer` (`CNr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Rent` (`CNr`, `MNr`, `CopyNr`, `DatoUt`, `DateInn`) VALUES
(1, 15, 1, '2020-01-01', '2020-01-30'),
(2, 15, 2, '2020-02-15', '2020-02-29');


/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

When I put it on SQL on PHPAdmin and click "GO", I got error because of CHECK ( DatoIn > DateUt) code.

And I remove that part, then I get "Rent" table empty of values.

What's wrong am I doing?

**Why is the "Rent" table empty of values when I put this on SQL on PHPMyAdmin?**

**Should I restructure the table relations?**

**And why "CHECK" doesn't work?**
The error message I get where I use CHECK:

[image: This is the Error I get]
[image]

Comment: *I got error because of CHECK* If you get an error, post the complete message. And of cause the statement

Comment: The check constraint should be `CHECK (\`DatoUt\` < \`DateInn\`)`, it doesn't make any sense for the in date to be before the out date. If you make that change it builds fine https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5fd4cb2b6dd248e267549f5ec7240858

Comment: @Nick I did as you said, and tried again. But still the "rent" table is empty of values. It only has columns (and their names) but no values.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Nick Server version: 10.2.26-MariaDB-log - MariaDB Server

Comment: @Coder88 it all works fine for me https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=5fd4cb2b6dd248e267549f5ec7240858

Comment: @Nick it works for me too in dbfiddle. But at PHPMyAdmin it doesn't work. The "rent" table is empty. I get the message  2 rows inserted. (Query took 0.0006 seconds.)
`INSERT INTO `Rent` (`CNr`, `MNr`, `CopyNr`, `DatoUt`, `DateInn`) VALUES (1, 15, 1, '2020-01-01', '2020-01-30'), (2, 15, 2, '2020-02-15', '2020-02-29')` But when I check the table via SELECT * FROM or via the user interface, there are no rows or data there.

Comment: @Coder88 unfortunately if we can't replicate the problem it's pretty hard to debug it... :-(

Comment: @Nick https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/index.php?route=/database/sql&db=TestBike in this link where you can test-drive the code and replicate the problem. I got the same problem on this test-account too.
I just added "new database" and clicked on that. Then clicked "SQL" from the top menu. I pasted the code there and clicked "go". I got the same errors as in my PHPmyAdmin account.

Comment: @Coder88 I just pasted your code into that website and it worked fine. phpMyAdmin did say there were syntax errors in the code around the `CHECK` but if you press `Go` anyway it executes fine. I've noticed that issue with phpMyAdmin before... take a look at the `test` database on that site and you'll see all the tables I just created, including `Rent` with two rows in it

Comment: @Nick Weird. In mine Rent is sill empty of rows. It says "2 rows inserted on Rent", but when I use "SELECT * FROM Rent;" or click on the "Browse" no rows appears. I can't see the "test" you made, maybe because it's a demo account and the databases just disappear.

Comment: @Coder88 I wish I could help but I've tried everything to replicate your problem and I can't...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207322/discussion-between-coder88-and-nick).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're seeing the syntax warning due to a bug in the parser used by phpMyAdmin which improperly marks this syntax as incorrect. I think that bug specifically is already reported as https://github.com/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/issues/167.

As nick indicates, you can still use the query despite the syntax warning.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the date out should've be less than the date in
CHECK (`DatoUt` < `DateInn`),